# Connection string for C# winapp with a SQL Server database file

Tags: c#, sql, database

This is not the first time I have used databases using the C# in asp.net, but I can't seem to make it work in a Winforms app.

This is a test face, so there is not a real database but a SQL Server database file that I created.

What I have is this:

```
public AddControl SaveResearcher(string name) 
{
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("")){
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Personell VALUES (@name, @function)", conn);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("name",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("function", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Researcher";
      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   return AddControl.OK;
}
```

What do I have to put in the connection string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection string for at sql server db file without username/password

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\pathtodb\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

You may find more connection string options at
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

You can check there,

[Connection strings for SQL Server 2005](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean soemthing like this?

```
"Data Source[SERVER_NAME];Initial Catalog=[DATABASE_NAME];Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

connectionString="Data Source=computerName\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!